# How to update 'id' in jQuery function after clicking on some div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, variables

I would like to simplistically describe my situation.

1st step: I want to increase variable "count" by 1 after each clicking on some div.

2nd step: I want to use updated "count" for my other function where I copy value from select element which id attribute contains updated "count" at the end of its id to input element which id attribute also contains updated "count" at the end of its id.

problem: updated "count" runs inside function smoothly where I copy value from select to input, but not in first #id selector where I use bind(). Here, "count" remains unchanged to "0". It causes that value of correct input element is still updated by wrong select element with "0" at the end of its id.

Can anyone advise me how to solve this situation with my variable ?

```
        $(document).ready(function () {

        var count= 0;
        $("#clickBtn").on("click", function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var textBox = document.getElementById("text");
            textBox.value = count;
            count++;
        });  

        $('#selectElmnt' + count).bind('change click keyup', function () {
            $('#inputElmnt' + count).val($(this).val());
        });
    });
```

Comment: The way this is written, the event binding function runs once, when count is 0 (also the bind method is deprecated in jQuery 3) ....   Depending on how the elements are laid out on the page, you could use event bubbling or capturing to accomplish this quite nicely.  Alternatively, if that is not feasible, you can create an event handler for #selectElmnt in your #clickBtn function, so it creates an event handler after count is updated. Lastly, you could add a new class to #selectElmt, and bind your event handler to the class (and look for the countID in that fn. Let me know if this is unlcear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both the functions `$("#clickBtn").on("click", function (event)` and `$('#selectElmnt' + count).bind` are running at page load (in `$(document).ready(`) at which point the value of `count` *is* zero.

I'm not quite clear what you are trying to achieve with the second function - if you want to bind a change/click/keyup event to all the selects with the various IDs you can do so at the start, if you want to trigger something based on the current count you need to do so inside the click callback.

For example, if you want to copy the value from select1 to input1, select2 to input2 then you don't need to worry about the count.  For that you could add the count as a data element and add a class, to give markup like:

```
<select id="selectElmnt1" class="selectElmnt" data-count="1">...</select>
<select id="selectElmnt2" class="selectElmnt" data-count="2">...</select>
<select id="selectElmnt3" class="selectElmnt" data-count="3">...</select>
```

Then use the following javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var count= 0;
    $("#clickBtn").on("click", function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var textBox = document.getElementById("text");
        textBox.value = count;
        count++;
    });  

    $('.selectElmnt').on('change click keyup', function () {
        var count_id = $(this).data('count');
        $('#inputElmnt' + count_id).val($(this).val());
    });
});
```

However, if you want to trigger something based on the button, you need something like:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var count= 0;
    $("#clickBtn").on("click", function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var textBox = document.getElementById("text");
        textBox.value = count;
        count++;
        // Trigger stuff here.  probably not bind, maybe just copy value now?
        $('#inputElmnt' + count_id).val( $('.selectElmnt' + count).val() );
    });         
});
```